# Display validation message on submitting the form in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to display validation message after user clicks on the submit form.
Eg Text box is required and user directly clicks on the submit button then the validation field should be displayed.

Here when the user clicks on the form nothing happens.

```
<body ng-controller="AppController as ctrl">

<form ng-submit="ctrl.submit()" name="myForm" novalidate>
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.username" name="uname" class="username" placeholder="Enter your name" required ng-minlength="3" />
    <span ng-show="myForm.$dirty && myForm.uname.$error.required">This is a required field</span>

    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.address" placeholder="Enter your Address" /><br /><br />

    <input type="email" ng-model="ctrl.user.email" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Enter your Email" required />
    <span ng-show="myForm.$dirty && myForm.email.$error.required">This is a required field</span>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js">
</script>
<script>
    angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('AppController', [function () {
        var self = this;
        self.submit = function () {
            console.log('Form is submitted with following user', self.user);
        };
    }]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When angular submit a form it make `$submitted` property on form level to `true`, also it adds `ng-submitted` class on `form`'s class attribute.

You could use `$submitted` property of form object like `myForm.$submitted` to identify that form has been submitted or not

```
ng-show="myForm.$submitted && myForm.uname.$error.required"
```

[**Demo Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZSqMm54kDnJuNOkVpr2C?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks,am am learning angular 1 can you suggest some useful links.